# List of reserved words for Google BigQuery legacy syntax

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I found the list of reserved keywords for Standard SQL, at [Standard SQL Lexical Structure - Lexical Structure - Reserved Keywords](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#reserved-keywords).

But I can't find the equivalent list for Legacy SQL, although there is a reference to it at [Legacy SQL Functions and Operators - Query Syntax - SELECT Clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql):

> You can use square brackets to escape reserved words so that you can use them as field name and aliases. For example, if you have a column named "prefix", which is a reserved word in BigQuery syntax, the queries referencing that field will fail with obscure error messages unless you escape it with square brackets

I know some of the keywords are different; for example Legacy SQL has `FLATTEN` which I assume is reserved, which Standard SQL does not.

Any pointers would help.

Comment: I also can't find it. Out of curiosity, why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a specific Google's public documentation that specify the **reserved words** list for BigQuery legacy service. The most accurate reference I found is the [Syntax differences](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) that points out the **escape reserved keywords** methods you can use in Standard and Legacy versions, as you well mentioned before.

Based on this, I think that the current workaround is to use the available [Reserved Keywords](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#reserved-keywords) list as a reference and escape the words that are marked as reserved while using BigQuery. Additionally, you can use **Send Feedback** button located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) public documentation in order to request the addition of the keywords list for Legacy SQL.